# If I pull the power on my computer and IMMEDIATELY restart it without booting OS, will RAM contents be preserved?

Tags: ram

I have DDR3 RAM in my computer. My computer is frozen and I have important unsaved work open. I've already dealt with the problem of how to recover and read the contents of RAM. I just need to be able to restart the computer with memory intact. If I lower the temperature of the RAM to do this, memory will be almost entirely preserved. However, this is a last resort. I'd prefer to do it through a quick reboot.

Comment: The contents of RAM are not modified by the act of rebooting.

Comment: Pulling power does empty RAM. And rebooting with an OS loaded overwrites the previous contents of RAM. I just want to know what time period I have to leave RAM without power before data loss begins.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Memory has to be retrained upon boot. I don't believe a warm-reset saves the trained data. Therefore during training, it will wipe out what's in memory.

Comment: @horta: Pushing the reset button does not touch the contents of memory. Most PC firmware does not explicitly erase RAM on startup. An OS will touch memory required to get it running, but again most do not explicitly erase RAM.

Comment: Many BIOS and OSes will test memory at startup, which would overwrite it.

Comment: Most of those "tests" are hokum. They merely check for presence.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to get this done. It MAY be possible, in an extreme emergency situation, to connect a remote debugger through an expansion slot and have the debugger seize control over the system bus, but that's a CIA-type last-ditch thing.

Remember, too, that although SOME of your work may still exist in RAM, it's possible that some of it may already have been paged to disk to make room for other things. Are you ready to sift through a frozen pagefile, looking for your data? In what format? Will you recognize it? Will it be compressed or otherwise modified for paging purposes? How big will the page blocks be? Will they be continuous? How large is your pagefile?

Even that which is still in RAM will need to be refreshed at a given rate to preserve any data it contains; without that all-important refresh, it loses data VERY VERY quickly, far too quickly for you to unpower the machine, then repower the machine (yielding to the power supply's required turn-on delay) and circumvent the bootup sequence, then wrest control from the CPU, THEN prepare to sift (in protected mode) through N gigs of space looking for your work.

It's gone. Your time will be better spent recreating your work, not trying to rescue it.

Comment: This paper says it's possible: http://citp.princeton.edu/pub/coldboot.pdf

Comment: That paper was written by ONE PERSON. So... one person says it's possible. Ok, I'll back down a little and grant a possibility. The probability, though, is so nearly zero that it's nearly uncountable.

Comment: Also, since your OS almost certainly uses virtual memory, your data may be anywhere in physical memory and split up on a page-by-page basis. Good luck putting it back together.

Answer (score 0):

From [this web site](http://www.sdram-technology.info/retention-tests.html):

> According to the JEDEC standard a DRAM cell must keep its
>   information/charge for a minimum time of 64 ms. By “keeping its
>   information” it is meant that the cell after every 64 ms still must
>   have enough charge inside it so that this charge will be recognized
>   correctly (as “1” or “0”) by the so called sense amplifiers.

I doubt RAM manufacturers will exceed this standard by much - so I think you're looking at 100ms max - that's probably not even enough to shut your computer down.
That being said, there is strong evidence that cooling the rams, or limiting the power outage is a viable option to recover RAM contents, assuming that:
a) you are able to boot into some OS that will not affect RAM
b) the computer powerup doesn't force a memory test
It seems that cooling the RAM will highten your chances of succes. I'm not sure what OS you could use that doesn't affect (most of) the computer's RAM - I guess a live Linux distribution with minimal memory use (no swap, 256k image or so) might enable you to do this.

Comment: "Recognized" is sort of a tricky word here. There will be enough residual charge after a few minutes have passed without power to distinguish 0s from 1s, but the chips themselves will be unable to do so.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams True - I'm assuming the point is to read the RAM 'normally', not using special invasive techniques.

Comment: @RJR I am using special techniques developed by researchers. This is the paper I'm using for the techniques: http://citpsite.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/oldsite-htdocs/pub/coldboot.pdf. With this in mind, is what I'm saying possible? Cut power, restart computer immediately, will all RAM contents be preserved?

Comment: @Rayman - I see. There various articles on the internet that make this more plausible; I've changed my answer. I'd suggest you try it out.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to recover the contents of DRAM for quite a long time after it loses power. However, some bits will have "decayed" which means in general you will not be able to reboot because the code will have errors.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cold_boot_attack